# Xpath IF for determining a value then if value is true count

Tags: xml, if-statement, xpath, conditional-statements, altova

For an IF statement in XPATH, What is the correct way to do something like:

```
xpath="if (x = 1000) then sum(SalesCount) else 0"
```

I tried this didn't worked. Thank you for the help.

*Edit*
Example:

```
<autocalc xpath="if (x = 1000) then sum(SalesCount) else 0">
     <styles font-family="Source Sans Pro" font-size="9pt"/> 
</autocalc>
```

This is used for altova 2013.

Comment: post some example xml

Comment: This is where I'm using XPATH:

`<autocalc xpath="if (x = 1000) then sum(SalesCount) else 0">
                        <styles font-family="Source Sans Pro" font-size="9pt"/>
                             </autocalc>`